# warning: always_inline function might not be inlinable [-Wattributes]

Tags: c

when i try to include a .h file which consists of definition for inline functions as

```
__attribute__( ( always_inline ) ) __STATIC_INLINE uint32_t __SLA (int32_t o1, int32_t o2, int32_t o3)
```

it is giving the "warning: always_inline function might not be inlinable [-Wattributes]" can you somebody help me i am struggling to fix it.

Comment: What compiler you are using ?

Comment: It *might* be that the compiler just cannot inline the function. What does it look like? And, oh, what compiler?

Comment: the compiler is "arm-none-eabi-gcc", the issue occurred as i was integrating my code into sdk by porting linux app into sdk so while porting i have to include the sdk's .h files to map the api's finally, that is giving trouble for me. and i see the same file is being used in many other existing folders of sdk without any warnings

Comment: compiler "arm-none-eabi-gcc"

Answer (score 60):

[For functions declared inline(!!!!)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html), this attribute inlines the function independent of any restrictions that otherwise apply to inlining.

So, when you set the attribute without declaring the function inline you will get these warning. Declare the function additionally inline will void these warnings. Behavior gnu gcc/g++ 5.30

```
# define FORCE_INLINE __attribute__((always_inline)) inline

FORCE_INLINE vec3 operator- (vec3 a, vec3 b) { vec3 t = { a.x-b.x, a.y-b.y, a.z-b.z }; return t; }
```

Answer (score 1):

What that warning is saying is that the compiler, is not always happy accepting your function as inline, or it wants it to be declared as inline.

I guess it's that `__attribute__ ((always_inline))` implies `inline` - in which case the parsing of the attribute needs to set `DECL_DECLARED_INLINE_P`.

The GCC manual specifies

> always_inline Generally, functions are not inlined unless optimization is specified. For functions declared inline, this attribute inlines the function even if no optimization level is specified.

Here's the `gcc` [test](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/vmx/gcc-bug-i.c?view=markup&pathrev=178730) for the revision

Answer (score 1):

### finally, after spending two days efforts found the solution as it is below

it is just because of a compiler(arm-none-eabi-gcc) option in Makefile
`CFLAGS= -D inline` if this flag is set, it throws warning as `__attribute__( ( always_inline ) ) __STATIC_INLINE(inline) uint32_t __SLA (int32_t o1, int32_t o2, int32_t o3)` when trying to include a .h file which consists of always inline functions

Comment: This explains nothing, `-D inline` just defines a preprocessor macro that does *something* not better specified to your specific `.h`. Neither the cause of the original message or what this did to fix it is clear.

Comment: It could explain it, although there's not quite enough information provided to be sure.  `-D inline` will define `inline` as an empty symbol, so the preprocessor will essentially remove `inline` from any function declarations.  Depending on GCC version etc, having `__attribute__((always_inline))` without also including `inline` can cause this error.

Comment: -D ```inline``` will define as empty symbol? does it define ```inline``` to 1?

Answer (score 1):

`__attribute__ ((always_inline))` does not imply "inline" in gcc. If you use `__attribute__ ((always_inline))` without also using "inline" then you will see this gcc warning message, unless it is disabled:

```
warning: 'always_inline' function might not be inlinable
```

In the original post I suspect that `__STATIC_INLINE(inline)` is intended to expand to `static inline`.

There may be other reasons why the function cannot be inlined, for example if it is recursive.